# Autocorrection words at the top of UITextView

Tags: objective-c

I have a UITextView and I need to show the autocorrection words suggested by apple at the top. Right now they are coming at the bottom and are hiding behind the editor. Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you might require to change frame y position for your view to little upwards. If possible provide screenshot for this issue.

Comment: By changing the y position, it will shift the textview to upwards. But what i need to show the auto correction bubble to above textview.

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot reference?

Comment: right now is it come above the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the predictive text

```
 [myTextField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes];
```

Comment: But it won’t take autocorrect bubble to upwards. Bubble still remains on downwards position.